# Do array elements have names by default in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var animals = ["cat","dog","fish"];
var lengths = animals.map(function(c) {
  return c.length;
});
console.log(lengths);//[3, 3, 4]
```

Here is the code. I don't understand where this 'c' argument comes from.
I tried to change this argument to another one (any word, actually, in both places), and the console.log result is always the same!

But this 'c' is not defined anywhere! Where does 'the engine' get the value of this 'c'?

Comment: `.map` takes each elements in a loop. Those elements comes in variable c. Its just a variable you can name it anything.

Comment: `c` is each item in the array and is passed as the first parameter to the `function` you're passing to `map()`

Comment: `.map` expects a `callback` function. This function takes 3 argument, [`currentElement`, `index`, `array`]. So no matter what you name it, it will be in this order only.

Answer (score 5):

You've asked two slightly different questions. First to the question body:

> I don't understand where this 'c' argument comes from. I tried to change this argument to another (any word, actually, in both places), and the console.log result is always the same!
>
> But this 'c' is not defined anywhere!
> Where does 'the engine' gets the value of this 'c'?

*You* define the parameter name (as you've noticed, you can choose any name for it you like). The value comes from the array, because `map` calls your callback and determines what argument to pass for that parameter.

Here's a **conceptual** implementaton of `Array.prototype.map`, which make make this clearer:

```js
// CONCEPTUAL ONLY, NOT AN ACTUAL VERSION OF IT
function maplike(array, callback) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = callback(array[i]);
        //                   ^^^^^^^^--- where 'c' comes from
    }
    return result;
}

var animals = ["cat","dog","fish"];
var lengths = maplike(animals, function(c) {
  return c.length;
});
console.log(lengths);//[3, 3, 4]
```

> Do array elements have names by default in JavaScript?

Sort of, but not in the way you're thinking. The name of the element is its index, `0`, `1`, etc. In fact, JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)* and those indexes are converted to string property names (in theory; in practice, JavaScript engines optimize it).

---

* *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Answer (score 4):

You're telling the interpreter how the parameter is called, here:

```
function(c) {
         ^
```

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) requires a callback that accepts up to 3 parameters. The first parameter is always the "current item", which you happen to have named `c`.

For a more in-depth explanation, have a look at [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)s **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45977954/1835379)**, as well.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, functions are [first class object](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first-class_object), which means they can be assigned to variables, passed as function parameters and returned from values. The `Array.prototype.map` function takes a function with it's first parameter denoting an item of the array. When invoked, the map function executes the given function for each of the items and creates a new array from the outputs of the given function.

In your case, you are defining the input function on the fly, inside the map function.

You can actually define the function outside and pass the function by reference inside map like below.

```
function getLength(item) {
    return item.length;
}

var animals = ["cat","dog","fish"];
var lengths = animals.map(getLength);

console.log(lengths);//[3, 3, 4]
```

Here, you can see it outputs the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not know what is the parameter named. You map an array. map function creates a new array in the lengths variable (variable being assigned to). How? It provides to the function parameter inside it, each element in the current array one-by-one by value. 
Here the value is actual string name ("cat" or "dog" or "fish").

In javascript, parameters can be optional. This map function can take three parameters, currentValue, index, array. In your case, c provides currentvalue.
If you would add one more parameter c,idx. Map function will get currentvalue and index inside it.

```
var animals = ["cat","dog","fish"];
var lengths = animals.map(function(c, idx, arr, test) {
   console.log(c); // currentvalue being processed in the array.
   console.log(idx);  // index of currentvalue in the array
   console.log(arr);  // original array being operated on.
   console.log(test); // undefined always. not available in map.
  return c.length;
});
console.log(lengths);//[3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That meant "map function creates a new array in the lengths variable (variable being assigned to)". I fixed above as well.arr being passed in current array.

Comment: Ehm, I had a bit of a brainfart. Disregard what I said before.